# tensorflow python framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, training-data

I have a problem while executing the model.fit() line in my python program. I got the following error on executing it. (Sorry for the bad format, I am new here). I don't know, where exactly I messed up with the code

Would be grateful for the suggestions!

> *2022-05-23 22:30:40.647915: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1722] OP_REQUIRES failed at cast_op.cc:121 : UNIMPLEMENTED: Cast string to float is not supported
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/user/Technical/CNNFaceDetector/main.py", line 73, in 
> model.fit(x_train_images, y_train_labels, epochs=3,
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1184, in fit
> tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
> tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
> **tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:**
>
> Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/Cast' defined at (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/user/Technical/CNNFaceDetector/main.py", line 73, in 
> model.fit(x_train_images, y_train_labels, epochs=3,
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1184, in fit
> tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 853, in train_function
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 842, in step_function
> outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 835, in run_step
> outputs = model.train_step(data)
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 788, in train_step
> loss = self.compiled_loss(
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 201, in **call**
> loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 141, in **call**
> losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 245, in call
> return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1737, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
> y_true = tf.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
> Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/Cast'
> **Cast string to float is not supported**
> [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/Cast}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_783]

```
IMAGE_SIZE = 48
labels = {'face': 0, 'non-face': 1}

faces_dir = 'Images/face'
non_faces_dir = 'Images/non-face'


def join_label(img, img_type):
    return img_type


x_train_images = []
y_train_labels = []

x_test_images = []
y_test_labels = ['face', 'non-face']


def import_and_create_training_data(img_type, DIRECTORY):
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(DIRECTORY)):
        img_label = join_label(img, img_type)
        path = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, img)
        img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))

        x_train_images.append(np.array(img))
        y_train_labels.append(str(img_label))


import_and_create_training_data(labels.get('face'), faces_dir)
import_and_create_training_data(labels.get('non-face'), non_faces_dir)

# print(len(x_train_images))
# X = np.array(x_train_images)
# X = X/255
# print(X.shape)


model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48, 48, 3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

test_images_dir = 'Images/Test_Images'

for img in tqdm(os.listdir(test_images_dir)):
    path = os.path.join(test_images_dir, img)
    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))

    x_test_images.append(np.array(img))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

x_train_images = np.array(x_train_images)
y_train_labels = np.array(y_train_labels)
x_test_images = np.array(x_test_images)
y_test_labels = np.array(y_train_labels)

model.fit(x_train_images, y_train_labels, epochs=3,
          validation_data=(x_test_images, y_test_labels))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the issue with [Cats-vs-Dogs](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/chetankv/dogs-cats-images) dataset.
The error is caused due to the following line

```
y_train_labels.append(str(img_label))
```

Replacing the above line with the following line of code will solve the issue

```
y_train_labels.append(np.array(img_label))
```

Please refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/434e441b38d2c6bed001648bc7028787/untitled84.ipynb#scrollTo=S5ujtLlQ6Rlm) for complete code.